# Treeview inside DropDown in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, treeview, drop-down-menu

I have a hierarchial dataset (like Geography --> Area-> Country -> State) which needs to be shown in a `TreeView`.  This was done, but the problem is, it is occupying toooo much space on the web page.

So I thought of using a drop down that would hold a treeview???  Got few samples from CodeProject with no success.

Any pointers or any other suggestion to solve my issue would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: Here's a thread on this topic on [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/1003245/1325999.aspx#1325999).

Answer (score 3):

Try to make use of dropdownExtendar in ajax toolkit controls.

Here is an example...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upArea" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtArea" runat="server" Width="100%" />
      <asp:DropDownExtender ID="txtArea_DropDownExtender" runat="server"  
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtArea" DropDownControlID="CourseTreeView">
      </asp:DropDownExtender>
      <asp:TreeView ID="CourseTreeView" runat="server"
       OnSelectedNodeChanged="CourseTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged"                                       ShowLines="true" DataSourceID="xdsArea" PopulateNodesFromClient="false" BackColor="#99CCFF" Width="232px">                                                                                           <Nodes>
          <asp:TreeNode Text="Gouse" PopulateOnDemand="false" Value="-1" />
            </Nodes>
         </asp:TreeView>
         <asp:XmlDataSource ID="xdsArea" runat="server" DataFile="~/XMLFile.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place it inside a `<div>` with the style option set to scroll if it overflows

```
<div style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;"> 
  //Treeview
</div>
```

Comment: I did something similar to this a while ago. It turned out pretty rad. I overloaded the dropdown functionality to instead show the div you imply. It basically became a re-imagined dropdown list. I used a multiplicity of nested divs to achieve a dashboard with filtering and the whole 9 yards.